# How to make an object 'imitate' other in python/pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Well, I'm trying to create a pacman with pygame, but I can't figure out how to make a persecution of the ghosts and the pacman. I tried this:

```
if keyup == True:
    y_position_pacman -= 1
    pygame.time.wait(50)
    y_position_ghost -= 1
```

It don't work how I want, only lag the game. What I want is that the ghost follow the player. An important observation is that the ghost need to find the player, not only imitate him. I am trying to do this since a lot of time but i can't figure out how to do it, Help?

Update: I don't know if there is any problem with that, but I'm brazilian. So my code is in portuguese. Fanstasma is ghost in portuguese, if it helps. Paracima is the variable for the key up, parabaixo, direita and esquerda are for down, right and left, respectively. Here is my whole code:

```
import pygame
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import *
while True:
  reiniciar = True
  tamanho_da_tela = (600, 600)
  x = 0
  y = 240
  y_2 = y + 46
  x_2 = x + 46
  pygame.init()

  #cores
  branco = (255, 255, 255)
  preto = (0, 0, 0)
  pygame.display.set_caption("PacMan por: Jean (^J^)")
  surface = pygame.display.set_mode(tamanho_da_tela)

  #declaracao de todos os elementos
  pacman_aberto_direita = pygame.image.load ("pacman_aberto.png")
  pacman_fechado = pygame.image.load ("pacman_fechado.png")
  pacman_aberto_cima = pygame.image.load ("pacman_aberto_cima.png")
  pacman_aberto_esquerda = pygame.image.load ("pacman_aberto_esquerda.png")
  pacman_aberto_baixo = pygame.image.load ("pacman_aberto_baixo.png")
  fantasma = pygame.image.load ("fantasma.png")
  fantasma1 = pygame.image.load ("fantasma1.png")
  morte = pygame.mixer.Sound("pacman_death.wav")
  som = pygame.mixer.Sound("pacman_chomp.wav")
  muro = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
  muro.image = pygame.image.load("muro.png")
  pacman = pacman_aberto_direita
  movimentar = True

  #variaveis das posicoes dos fantasmas
  fx = 500
  fy = 100
  fx1 = 450
  fy1 = 100

  #mapa
  m = 1
  v = 0
  cores = {
    m : preto,
    v : branco
    }
  mapa = [ 
    [v,v,v,v,m,v,v,v,v,v,v,m],
    [v,v,v,m,m,v,m,m,m,m,m,v],
    [v,m,v,v,v,v,m,v,v,v,v,v],
    [v,m,v,m,m,v,m,v,v,v,m,v],
    [v,m,v,m,v,v,m,m,m,m,m,v],
    [v,m,v,m,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v],
    [v,v,v,m,v,m,v,m,v,m,v,v],
    [v,m,v,m,v,m,v,m,v,m,v,m],
    [v,m,m,m,v,m,v,m,v,v,v,v],
    [v,v,v,v,v,m,v,m,v,m,m,v],
    [m,m,m,m,m,m,v,m,v,m,v,v],
    [v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,m]
  ]
  tamanho_tile = 50
  altura_mapa = 12
  largura_mapa = 12

  def colided(column, row):
    if mapa[int(row/50)][int(column/50)] == m:
      return True
    else:  
      return False
  def colidec(column, row):
    if mapa[int(row/50)][int(column/50)] == m:
      return True
    else:  
      return False
  def colideb(column, row):
    if mapa[int(row/50)][int(column/50)] == m:
      return True
    else:  
      return False
  def colidee(column, row):
    if mapa[int(row/50)][int(column/50)] == m:
      return True
    else:  
      return False
  pacman = pacman_aberto_direita
  tamanho_tile_detect = 46

  def detectacolisao(x,y,tamanho_tile_detect,fx,fy,fx1,fy1):
    if (fx+tamanho_tile_detect>=x>=fx and fy+tamanho_tile_detect>=y>=fy):
        return True

elif (fx+tamanho_tile_detect>=x+tamanho_tile_detect>=fx and fy+tamanho_tile_detect>=y>=fy):
    return True

elif (fx+tamanho_tile_detect>=x>=fx and fy+tamanho_tile_detect>=y+tamanho_tile_detect>=fy):
    return True

elif (fx+tamanho_tile_detect>=x+tamanho_tile_detect>=fx and fy+tamanho_tile_detect>=y>=fy):
    return True

elif (fx1+tamanho_tile_detect>=x>=fx1 and fy1+tamanho_tile_detect>=y>=fy1):
    return True

elif (fx1+tamanho_tile_detect>=x+tamanho_tile_detect>=fx1 and fy1+tamanho_tile_detect>=y>=fy1):
    return True

elif (fx1+tamanho_tile_detect>=x>=fx1 and fy1+tamanho_tile_detect>=y+tamanho_tile_detect>=fy1):
    return True

elif (fx1+tamanho_tile_detect>=x+tamanho_tile_detect>=fx1 and fy1+tamanho_tile_detect>=y>=fy1):
    return True

else:
    return False
```

#loop para manter o jogo aberto

```
while reiniciar:

#limpeza da tela para nao bugar o grafico do pacman e outros elementos. cria um novo fundo todo fim de while
pygame.draw.rect( surface, (255, 255, 255),   (0, 0, 600, 600) )

#introducao do mapa (tiles)
for row in range(0, 12):
  for column in range(0, 12):
    pygame.draw.rect( surface, (255, 255, 255),   (row*tamanho_tile, column*tamanho_tile, 50, 50) )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(60)

#facilitar o uso das teclas de direcao
paracima = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_UP]
parabaixo = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_DOWN]
direita = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_RIGHT]
esquerda = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_LEFT]

#introducao dos pontos
for row in range(0, 12):
  for column in range(0, 12):
    pygame.draw.rect( surface, cores[mapa[row][column]], (column*tamanho_tile, row*tamanho_tile, 50, 50) )

#introducao dos elementos na interface
surface.blit ( pacman, (x, y) )
surface.blit ( fantasma, (fx, fy) )
surface.blit ( fantasma1, (fx1, fy1) )

#era pra ser a inteligencia dos fantasmas


#movimentos do pacman
if paracima == True:
  pacman = pacman_aberto_cima
  if colidec(x, y - 2):
    pass
  else:
    y -= 2.5
    pygame.time.wait(50)
    fy -= 2.5
    fy1 -= 2.5

if parabaixo == True:
  pacman = pacman_aberto_baixo
  if colideb(x, y + 48):
    pass
  else:
    y += 2.5
    pygame.time.wait(50)
    fy += 2.5
    fy1 += 2.5

if direita == True:
  pacman = pacman_aberto_direita
  if colided(x + 48, y):
    pass
  else:
    x += 2.5
    pygame.time.wait(50)
    fx += 2.5
    fx1 += 2.5

if esquerda == True:
  pacman = pacman_aberto_esquerda
  if colidee(x - 2, y):
    pass
  else:
    x -= 2.5
    pygame.time.wait(50)
    fx -= 2.5
    fx1 -= 2.5

#colisao com os pontos
#for x in range(int(x, x + 50)) and y in range(int(y, y + 50)) == p1 or p2:"
  #p1 = v
  #p2 = v

#colisao do pacman com fantasma e fantasma1
if detectacolisao(x,y,tamanho_tile,fx,fy,fx1,fy1) == True:
  morte.play()
  pygame.time.wait(1800)
  reiniciar = False

#colisao do pacman e fantasmas
if x < 1:
  x += 2.5
if x > 553:
  x -= 2.5
if y < 1:
  y += 2.5
if y > 553:
  y -= 2.5

if fx < 0:
  fx += 2.5
if fx > 550:
  fx -= 2.5
if fy < 0:
  fy += 2.5
if fy > 550:
  fy -= 2.5

if fx1 < 0:
  fx1 += 2.5
if fx1 > 550:
  fx1 -= 2.5
if fy1 < 0:
  fy1 += 2.5
if fy1 > 550:
  fy1 -= 2.5

#evento de saida
for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit()

#nem lembro. atualizar a tela?
pygame.display.flip()
```

"#movimentos do pacman" is the part of the movements. "X" is pacman's x coordinate, fx is ghost's x coordinate and fx1 is ghost2's x coordinate.

Comment: A* pathfinding my friend.

Comment: I think you're going to want to do some research on dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Read through this: http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior

Comment: don't use `pygame.time.wait`, `time.sleep` and `"long-running loops"` because it stops `mainloop` (and all functions in game).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first thought the question being asked here was why the game was lagging, thus the other post. This post contains information on the pathfinding of the enemy ghost to the pacman player.

### Solution 1 (horribly ineffective)

---

You could move the ghost in the direction of the pacman. (NOT the same as the solution in the answer, which moves the ghost the same movement the pacman is given).
By this, I mean that if pacman is to the right of the ghost, the ghost moves right every frame until it's on top of pacman. A coded example would be:

```
def pathfindToPlayer():
    # X and Y are the ghost's location attributes
    pac_x, pac_y = pacman.x, pacman.y # Pacman's location attributes

    tomove_x = pac_x-self.x # Get difference between x locations
    tomove_x = cmp(abs(tomove_x), tomove_x) # Normalize to positive/negative 1

    # repeat with y values
    tomove_y = pac_y-self.y
    tomove_y = cmp(abs(tomove_y), tomove_y)

    # apply location offsets to ghost
    if tomove_x != 0: # try to move x before y, diagonal moves not allowed
        self.x += tomove_x
    else:
        self.y += tomove_y
```

### Solution 2

---

This solution involves using the actual map to determine where it can and can't move, while still moving towards pacman.

```
gamemap = [
    [0,   0, 0, 0, 0  ],
    ['p', 0, 0, 0, 0  ],
    [0,   1, 1, 1, 0  ],
    [0,   0, 0, 1, 0  ],
    [0,   0, 0, 1,'g' ]
]
def pathfindToPlayer():
    '''
    Same stuff here as the above function, without applying the offsets yet
    '''
    if gamemap[self.x+tomove_x][self.y] != 1: # If there isn't a wall
        self.x += tomove_x
    elif gamemap[self.x][self.y+tomove_y] != 1: # If there isn't a wall
        self.y += tomove_y
    else:
        print "Can't move closer to Pacman"
```

### Solution 3 - Using a pathfinding algorithm

---

If the above two solutions aren't strong enough for what you want, then you could use one of many pathfinding algorithms out there. The reason I chose the two solutions above to share is because they're short, simple and easily fit in an answer without much explaining.

Here's some links to help you out with a pathfinding algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding#Algorithms_used_in_pathfinding
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28041/path-finding-algorithms
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-the-state-of-the-art-pathfinding-algorithms-for-changing-graphs-d-d-l

Comment: I guess it will work. But I didn't understand the second option (I will use the second) very well... I need to add what is inside of the definition of the second option into the first?

Comment: @jeanalves In the second solution, replace the multiline comment with everything in the first solution up to the point where the offsets are applied to the ghosts location.

Answer (score 1):

time.wait(50) stops the whole program for 50 milliseconds so that will not work. If your program has a main loop, how about executing ghost follow movements in every 10th or n:th loop?

Comment: That's a good ideia, but how do I do that INSIDE of my main loop? It is inside of a if some_key boolean

Answer (score 0):

The thing with visual games is that there's a main block called a *game loop*. Without having a different thread or process handling the game logic like your ghost movement you put in your question, then you shouldn't do anything that blocks your code. What you want to do is update the ghost's position every *frame* instead of waiting a certain amount of time. For example:

```
def gameLogic(keysPressed):
    if keysPressed["up"]: # Only one case for the movement, the rest is common sense
        y_position_pacman -= 1
    ghost.pathfindTo(id="player") # You'll have to implement this method yourself

# Main game loop
while gameRunning:
    keysPressed = handleInput()
    gameLogic(keysPressed)
    render()
    fpsClock.tick(60) # Tick the created fpsClock object to limit the game to 60 fps
```

Comment: I know that, but I want to update the ghost's position making the position follow pacman's position.